# How do I append a character to my existing csv file?

Tags: matlab, octave

So I have a csv in the form

```
1,2,3,4,5 

6,7,8,9,10
```

and so on.

However what I want to be able to do is append a string character at the end of each record like

```
1,2,3,4,5,A 

6,7,8,9,10, B
```

and so on.

Is there anyway to do this efficiently in matlab/octave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matlab a possible solution could be:

```
test= readtable('Test.csv');

sz=size(test);

Alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

for i=1:sz(1)
    test(i,sz(2)+1)={Alphabet(i)};
end

writetable(test,'Test.csv','Delimiter',',','WriteVariableNames',0);
```

The strings you want to add are to be defined in the variable `Alphabet` and `Test.csv` is to be replaced by your filename. You can even change the Delimiter if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this nicely by using the [ASCII representation](http://www.asciitable.com/) of the letters.

```
% Read input table.
inputTable = readtable('q57422719.csv','Format','%s%s%s%s%s');

% Determine number of rows.
nRows = size(inputTable,1);

% ASCII offset for capital A
asciiOffset = 65;

% Create letters vector.
letters = char((asciiOffset:1:asciiOffset+nRows-1)');

% Create output table.
outputTable = inputTable;

% Append letters at end of rows.
outputTable = [outputTable cellstr(letters)];

% Write to file.
writetable(outputTable,'q57422719_output.csv','WriteVariableNames',0);
```

Of course if you have more than 26 letters, then the code would use the next characters (`[`, `\` and so on).

---

For input file:

```
1,2,3,4,5 
6,7,8,9,10
```

the output is:

```
1,2,3,4,5,A
6,7,8,9,10,B
```

Comment: This is also a neat way to do it. Thanks